# Having some build issues on an app developed by someone else: ld: library not found for -lAdServer_Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

The build error I am getting is:

ld: library not found for -lAdServer_Iphone

I have experience in making apps from scratch. However the issue I am having is not having enough experience importing existing apps and making them work.

Would someone be able to give me some clarity on this?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that you did not copy the library called 'IAdServer_iPhone' to the proper location.  To fix this, either get the location the project is linking to and copy the library there, or you can reimport the library from the new location.

Comment: I can't find this library anywhere!